# How can I use the point type coordinate information of postgis in graphql using mutations?

Tags: postgresql, graphql, nestjs, postgis, typeorm

I created a mutation to insert new data into the postgresql called location. The column coordinate must receive and store data, for example, ST_GeomFromGeoJSON ('{ "type": "Point", "coordinates": [-48.23456,20.12345]}').

However, graphql is not working, so I don't know where to modify it. I think it's because the scalar called GeoJSONPoint that I made is not working properly. Could you tell me how to create a scalar if graphql puts the data above?

GeoJSONPoint Scalar

```
import { GraphQLScalarType, Kind } from 'graphql';

export const GeoJSONPoint = new GraphQLScalarType({
    name: 'GeoJSONPoint',
    description: 'Geometry scalar type',
    parseValue(value) {
        return value;
    },

    serialize(value) {
        return value;
    },

    parseLiteral(ast) {
        if (ast.kind === Kind.OBJECT) {
            console.log(ast);
            return new Object(ast);
        }
        return null;
    }
});
```

location.entity

```
import {
    Column,
    CreateDateColumn,
    Entity,
    JoinColumn,
    ManyToOne,
    PrimaryGeneratedColumn
} from 'typeorm';
import { Location_Group } from './location_group.entity';
import { Geometry } from 'geojson';
import { Field, ID, Int, ObjectType } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { GeoJSONPoint } from 'src/scalar/geoJSONPoint.scalar';

@ObjectType()
@Entity('location')
export class Location {
    @Field(() => ID)
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('increment')
    id: number;

    @Field(() => String)
    @Column({ type: 'varchar' })
    name: string;

    @Field(() => GeoJSONPoint)
    @Column({
        type: 'geometry',
        nullable: true,
        spatialFeatureType: 'Point',
        srid: 4326
    })
    coordinate: Geometry;

    @Field(() => Int)
    @Column({ type: 'int' })
    order_number: number;

    @Field()
    @CreateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamptz' })
    created_at: Date;

    @Field(() => Location_Group)
    @ManyToOne(
        () => Location_Group,
        (location_group) => location_group.location
    )
    @JoinColumn([{ name: 'location_group_id', referencedColumnName: 'id' }])
    location_group: Location_Group;
}
```

resolver

```
    @Mutation(() => Location)
    async createLocation(
        @Args('data') data: LocationDataInput
    ): Promise<Location> {
        console.log(data);
        return await this.locationService.setLocation(data);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: I solved this problem. First of all, we divided the values entered by parseLiteral in scalar into {type: '', coordinates: []} and removed the foreign key column. Thank you for your interest.

Comment: Please pot answer here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. First of all, we divided the values entered by `parseLiteral` in scalar into

```
{type: '', coordinates: []}
```

and removed the foreign key column.